# SWIG/Python - Passing array of typedef values

Tags: python, swig

I'm trying to wrap a C function with this signature:

```
typedef unsigned short UINT16;
void print_uint16_array(UINT16 x[3]);
```

starting with the example from http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_carrays

I have it working fine for the case in the example (double) and for non-typedef'd `unsigned short`, but when I try to do use UINT16 Python complains that I'm passing the wrong argument type (`TypeError: in method 'print_uint16_array', argument 1 of type 'UINT16 [3]'`).

Here's what I have right now, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

print_array.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_ushort_array(unsigned short x[3]) {
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { printf("[%d] = %d\n", i, x[i]); }
}

typedef unsigned short UINT16;
void print_uint16_array(UINT16 x[3]) {
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { printf("[%d] = %d\n", i, x[i]); }
}
```

print_array.i

```
%module print_array
%include "carrays.i"

%{
typedef unsigned short UINT16;

void print_ushort_array(unsigned short x[3]);
void print_uint16_array(UINT16 x[3]);
%}

typedef unsigned short UINT16;

%array_class(unsigned short, ushortArray);
%array_class(UINT16        , uint16Array);


void print_ushort_array(unsigned short x[3]);
void print_uint16_array(UINT16 x[3]);
```

test.py

```
from print_array import *
ushort_array = ushortArray(3)
uint16_array = uint16Array(3)

print_ushort_array(ushort_array)
print_uint16_array(uint16_array)
```

Build/Test:

```
$ swig -python print_array.i
$ gcc -shared print_array*.c -o _print_array.pyd -I /c/Miniconda/include -L /c/Miniconda -lpython27

    $ /c/Miniconda/python test.py
[0] = 0
[1] = 0
[2] = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print_uint16_array(uint16_array)
TypeError: in method 'print_uint16_array', argument 1 of type 'UINT16 [3]'
```

Comment: If you insert `%array_functions(UINT16, altArray)` and use `print_array.print_uint16_array(print_array.new_altArray(3))` you can do what you want

Comment: It is happier with that... any idea why the array class won't work?  I was using the class so could populate the values using [] notation... uint16_arry[0]=1, etc.

Comment: I would say it is a bug - you could try to fix it by looking into `carrays.i`. Personally, I use `numpy.i` and have made a lot of improvements to that. With NumPy, you have many more advantages than just `[]`